# Unable to get 'string' after iteration the list

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, aiogram

everyone. I have a question to be clarified:
I'm 'building' a telegram bot (aiogram) for car renting which designed to guide user while choosing the car for rent. In one of sub menu's i want to list the car brands to let user go through filters and pick what he wants. But the brands available in the 'fleet' may vary time to time. So amount of buttons will vary too. So i need a function to generate the buttons in place based on cars available.

- Bot has keyboard menus and Inline menus
- Bot linked with PostgreSQL DataBase which would be updated

Considering facts above : i've created a function to generate the Inline buttons. But i faced the problem with iteration of the list received from fetching the DB. After iteration of fetched data i'm getting None type of every list object. And for creating the Inline button i need name and callback sign in 'string' type. How can i manage this case? Attaching my code below.
P.S. Apologising for my english in advance and thanx for any help.

```
#DB Connection

try: 
    connect = psycopg2.connect(database = 'car_rental', 
                        user = 'postgres', 
                        password = 'datapass')
    curs = connect.cursor()
    curs.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT brand
                    FROM fleet
                    WHERE category = 'economy'""")
   
    economy_brands_list = [x[0] for x in curs.fetchall()]

except:
    print('oops. DB die')
finally:
    curs.close()
    connect.close()

#function to generate Inline buttons
def economy_bt_generator(): # Function generates the amount of inline buttons (brands in this case) depends on DB condition
    final_expression = 'InlineKeyboardMarkup()'
    for variable in lst:
        final_expression += f'.add(InlineKeyboardButton({variable}, callback_data={variable.lower()}))'
    return final_expression

#output of the fucntion
InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton(VW, callback_data=vw)).add(InlineKeyboardButton(Ford, callback_data=ford)).add(InlineKeyboardButton(Seat, callback_data=seat)).add(InlineKeyboardButton(Nissan, callback_data=nissan)).add(InlineKeyboardButton(KIA, callback_data=kia)).add(InlineKeyboardButton(Skoda, callback_data=skoda)).add(InlineKeyboardButton(Toyota, callback_data=toyota)).add(InlineKeyboardButton(Hyundai, callback_data=hyundai)).add(InlineKeyboardButton(Suzuki, callback_data=suzuki)).add(InlineKeyboardButton(Renault, callback_data=renault)).add(InlineKeyboardButton(Ravon, callback_data=ravon))
```

So i need to convert every brand name into string 'brand_name'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting quotes around the variables in the f-string. So that your code:

```py
final_expression += f'.add(InlineKeyboardButton({variable}, callback_data={variable.lower()}))'
```

becomes this:

```py
final_expression += f'.add(InlineKeyboardButton("{variable}", callback_data="{variable.lower()}"))'
```

Comment: Hm, that one works. Strange, becouse i did this at first and got Syntax Error. Probably due to 'f'  formating. But now i'm getting JSON parsing error. But if i copy the content which returns by function manualy and insert into Keyboard Markup it works fine.

Comment: Thanks alot for help. Problem with 'aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object' was solved by returning `eval(final_expression)`